# Не работает своя функция в opencart 2.0

Tags: php, cms, opencart

подскажите почему не работает своя функция в opecart 2.0 делаю так в контролере:

```
$data['margin'] = $this->model_query_query->getMargin(); // тут 10
$data['convert'] = number_format($this->currency->convert('1', 'CNY', $this->currency->getCode()) + 0.07,2); //тут получаем 1,36
```

в представлении так:

```
function conver($prise){
    $convertor = $prise * $convert;
    $prosent = $convertor / 100 * $margin + $convertor;
    return $prosent;
}
echo conver('100'); //ответь должен быть 110
```

получаю ошибку: `Undefined variable: convert in`

Comment: переменная $convert НЕ объявлена в теле функции. А так же не объявлена $margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$convert и $margin в файле представления - локальные. Область их видимости - функция. Передайте им значения:

```
function conver($prise, $margin, $convert){...
```

**UPD(не в тему, но всё же).:**

А зачем вы, собственно, определяете функцию в представлении. OC это MVC система, и этим вы нарушаете логику. Поддерживать такой код станет труднее. Я как разраб ожидаю увидеть во вьюхе исключительно переменные со значениями, но не как не функции. Логику я буду искать в моделях и контроллерах. Избегайте такого подхода, используйте функции в файлах представления только в js скриптах, IMHO.

Comment: В моей ситуации я уже получаю готовый json из api, по этому в контролере я не сделал подбор массив с данными а просто пропускаю то что нужно через самодельный функции.

Comment: Вам ведь ничего не мешает принять json и определить функцию conver в контроллере, а во вьюху передать результат этой функции. Но это вопрос чистоты кода, не более.

Comment: Да так более чисто получится, но как по мне будет клонирования что казалось не логично, я лично делаю так в контролере: `$data['json'] = $json;` и в вьюхе `$json->price $json->item` а не так что бы сначала в контролере: `$data['price'] = $json->price; $data['item'] = $json->item;` потом в вьюху `$price; $item;`